# In how many ways can the letters of the english alphabet be arranged s

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can the letters of the english alphabet be arranged
> so that there are seven letter between the letters A and B, and no
> letter is repeated?

I have searched this question and have seen many interpretations.

> **Answer-1 (source: [answers.yahoo.com](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20150120074748AA3j1s4))**
>
> Ans: 24 x 23 x 22 x21 x20 x19 x 18

.

> **Answer-2: (source: [m4maths.com](http://www.m4maths.com/39038-in-how-many-ways-can-letters-of-the-english-alphabet-be-arranged-so-that-there-are-7-letters-between-A.html))**
>
> Ans 24P7 * 2 * 18

.

> **Answer-3: (source: [careerbless](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=2413#top))**
> Ans: 24!*36

.

> **My solution**
>
> since there are 36 positions for A and B (1-9, 9-1,
> 2-10,10-2, ...18-26,26-18) and remaining 24 letters can be positioned
> in 24! ways, to me, the third answer 24!*36 appears right. Please tell
> if this is correct.

Comment: In your solution you meant 36 positions for A and B.

Comment: @user21820 thx, it was a typo, corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. 18 positions for the pair (A,B), and 2! ways to arrange them in those positions, and 24! ways to put the remaining 24.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different approach, just to confirm your answer:

- Choose a place for A and put B appropriately ahead: $26-(7+1)$ options
- Reorder A and B in every possible way: $2!$ options
- Choose $7$ letters out of the letters between C and Z: $\binom{26-2}{7}$
- Reorder those $7$ letters in every possible way: $7!$ options
- Reorder the remaining letters in every possible way: $(26-2-7)!$ options

The answer is therefore: $(26-(7+1))\cdot2!\cdot\binom{26-2}{7}\cdot7!\cdot(26-2-7)!=24!\cdot36$